# SSI regexp простой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ssi

Есть вот такое

```
<!--#if expr="\"$REQUEST_URI\" = \"/arenda/black.html\"" -->
```

Все ок. Но мне нужно, чтобы еще это срабатывало для

```
/arenda/black1.html
/arenda/black2.html
/arenda/black3.html
```

И т.д.

Причем для

```
/arenda/black2_p2.html
```

Уже не нужно, чтобы работало. Просто добавить любые цифры после black

Я делаю так - но что-то не так.

```
<!--#if expr="\"$REQUEST_URI\" = \"/arenda/black\([0-9]+)\.html\"" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
 /arenda/black[\d]+.html
```

Comment: В такой конструкции не работает
<!--#if expr="\"$REQUEST_URI\" = \"/arenda/black[\d]+.html\"" -->

Comment: а так <!--#if expr="\"$REQUEST_URI\" = \"/arenda/black[\\d]+.html\"" -->